# URL Rewrite Regular Expression to suit all

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting, web-config

### Brief Explanation

I am trying to come up with a smart way of controlling my web page rewrites with as few rewrites as possible.

So, for example, if you have the following page translations:

```
'domain.com/test/'        => 'domain.com/test.php'
'domain.com/errors/404/'  => 'domain.com/errors.php?code=404'
```

You **could** have individual rewrites for every page... However, I like to minimise this by instead having one regular expression to suit all. So the regular expression to match the above would be:

```
^([a-z0-9\-]+)\/?([a-z0-9\-]+)?\/?$
```

and then the matches would be placed into the URL like so *(note that `code` would be replaced by `request` on the errors page)*:

```
domain.com/$1.php?request=$2
```

*and then you could append the query string...*

**Obviously in some cases you need individual rewrites, but you can usually minimise this by using clever regular expressions and well structured pages.**

### My Problem

Similar to the above example, I have pages within my site that are rewritten with this exact regular expression. So the following pages translate like so:

```
'domain.com/shipments/open/' => 'domain.com/shipments.php?request=open'
'domain.com/settings/user/'  => 'domain.com/settings.php?request=user'
etc...
```

However, for reasons which I will not go into, I also have pages written like so:

```
'domain.com/shipment/edit'
```

Notice the it says **shipment** not **shipments**! Despite this, I still want this to be rewritten to the **shipments** page. So the translation would look like this:

```
'domain.com/shipment/edit' => 'domain.com/shipments.php?request=edit'
```

I cannot think of a way other than another rewrite that specifies that **shipment** is an alias for **shipments**...

One of the reasons I do not want individual rewrites for this is that I am not just talking about shipments, there are many documents that I need to alias, and therefore would rather not go down the multiple rewrite route as my web.config file will get pretty darn large.

I have come up with the following solutions (but obviously I am not happy with them):

1. Have a page in my root directory called shipment.php and just include the contents of shipments.php
2. Write rewrites for each page with an alias...

I cannot think of another (better) way of doing this, can any of you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only have 1 exception, why not add that one exception ?

We will use a "rewrite rewrite technique" (I just came up with that name lol)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+[^s/])s*/?([a-z0-9-]+)?/?$ $1s/$2 [NC]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/?([a-z0-9-]+)?/?$ $1.php?request=$2
```

Tested on localhost and this [RewriteRuleTester](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/).

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but as I state in my question, it is not just the one exception... I simply used shipment as an example

Comment: @BenCarey See updated answer, this time it will remove the `s` from the end. So it may be problematic if a word actually ends with a `s` in it's singular form.

Comment: @BenCarey That doesn't matter, if the first match fails, it means it has no "s" at the end so it will proceed with the second one.

Comment: I want shipment to be an alias of shipments, so I actually would like this the other way around... However, it seems that there is no other solution to this other than having exceptions. I feared that would be the case, but its not the end of the world. I will accept your answer as it confirms what I originally suspected. Thanks for your help. :-)

Comment: @BenCarey lol sorry, but try again and tell me if that's what you needed :D